# Struts2 XML validation with bootstrap theme

Tags: struts2

I have struts2 application working great with its own theme and there is no issue at all.
with bootstrap theme the forms are showing error field if left blank but form getting submitted with null values.
So the xml validation is not working which I can conclude myself.

Please help me techies I couldn't find any support regarding the specific error.

Bootstrap 3
Struts2 with normal JSP pages.

Comment: I don't think that bootstrap plugin is supporting Bootstrap 3

Comment: Thanks Roman.But the login page is working fine.The problem with other forms in the application.

Comment: You can write forms with B2, there's a plugin 200 but I've used 17